# Trigger not firing when logged in as user who is not a system admin

Tags: trigger, permissions

I have a trigger which creates as many child records as specified in the parent record's picklist field. This works fine when logged in as System admin but when logged in as some other user who is not an admin, it performs no action. I have given permissions to the handler and utility classes  of the trigger to the user too.

Comment: Does this user have permission to create records of the child object?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes.

Comment: And they have read access to that picklist field?

Comment: Have you done any debugging at all? You have the more information that we do to debug it. Capture a debug log and analyze the results.